# Using `bisect_left()` on dict() raising `dict is not a sequence` error. How to traverse a dict() to improve search process time

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here'a my code. I'm trying to create a dict from a word file and use it for search process. I use `bisect_left()` on `lists` using the same on `dict()` raises a sequence error

```
import bisect
fln = open("CROSSWD.TXT")

def create_dict(x):
    new_dict=dict()
    i=0
    for line in x:
        word=line.strip()
        new_dict[word]= i
        i+=1
    return new_dict #create a new_dict
```

How to use bisect_left on a dict?

```
def search_dict(new_dict,s):
    i= bisect_left(new_dict,s) #raises a sequence error. what other method can I use?
    if s in new_dict[i]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
                            
s='zebra'

new_dict=create_dict(fln)

if search_dict(new_dict,s):
    print(s," in dict")
else:
    print(s," not in dict")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bisect_left` requires an object that which supports integer indexing, since the bisection algorithm needs to know what the "middle" element is in order to bisect the sequence. The C implementation of `bisect_left` confusingly raises a `TypeError` claiming that an object of type `dict` has no length. While that claim is false, it *is* better to detect and reject a `dict` argument earlier than the pure Python version (see below) would.

That said, there's no *need* to use `bisect` on a `dict`: a `dict`'s purpose is to allow O(1) access to an object via hashing, rather than having to search for it O(log n) time via binary search.

---

The pure Python version of `bisect_left`, minus some comments:

```
def bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if a[mid] < x: lo = mid+1
        else: hi = mid
    return lo
```

Notice that `len(a)` is computed with the assumption that you can latter index `a` using an integer derived from the length. That isn't true of a `dict` (or if you don't get a `KeyError`, it's certainly  not going to help you in locating your target). Also, once the `bisect` module defines pure Python functions, it attempts to replace them with pure C functions imported from `_bisect`. *Those* functions apparently make a check early to ensure that `a` is not a `dict`. The error message raised is a bit misleading.

Comment: So, the search time is a constant irrespective of the size of the dataset?

Comment: Yes, that's how a hash table works: it's essentially just an array and a function that maps a value to an integer used to index the array.

Comment: "*dict does not support len*" is confusing, if not plain wrong.  Maybe it's better to say "*dict does not support positional indexing*" or similar.  I'm not sure what you mean by saying "*Its various iterators do*" either, the various dict iterators support neither `len` nor positional indexing.

Comment: Agreed, but I worded it that way because that's the gist of the error message raised by `bisect_left` itself: `bisect_left({}, "foo")` yields `TypeError: object of type 'dict' has no len()`, which led to the giant addendum. I'll reword the first paragraph.

Comment: That strange error message is only on older Python versions.  Now it should be `TypeError: dict is not a sequence`, which sounds more like the error which OP described anyway ([bpo33933](https://bugs.python.org/issue33933), [GH7846](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/7846))

Comment: @wim Ah, OK, it just changed in Python 3.8.